# Jquery validation plugin | resetForm is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to clear all error messages as well error highlighting when user click on the `clear form` button, below are actual requirements

1. Validate form using Jquery validation
2. When user click on a field error message should be cleared (per field)
3. On clicking reset button, every error should be cleared

here is my code

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   var validator = $("#register_form").validate({
   validator.resetForm();
   focusCleanup: true,
 rules: {
  // custom rules
},
messages: {
// custom messages
    }
  });
```

For me, first 2 things are working, but when I am trying to clear complete form, I am not able to do this.this is how I am trying to clear it

```
function clearInputForm(){
  alert("");
  var validator1 = $( "#register_form" ).validate();
  validator1.resetForm();
   $("#register_form")[0].reset();
}
```

But nothing is happening , though with  `$("#register_form")[0].reset();`, form fields are getting clear, but error messages are not getting cleared.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eV2Nd/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Thanks, but in my case `click` event not getting triggered, issue seems to be with `validator.resetForm();` inside  `$("#register_form").validate` which is required to clear per fields error messages

Comment: So whatever happened with this?  The answers below are not good enough for some reason?

Answer (score 12):

**Quote OP:**

> *1) Validate form using Jquery validation*

**You cannot put the `validator.resetForm();` method inside of the `.validate()` method**.

`.validate()` is a plugin method where the only thing that can go inside is a comma separated map of the *allowed* options, `{option:value, option:value, etc.}`, as per [the `.validate()` method documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

[`resetForm()` method documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.resetForm/)

```
$("#register_form").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true
        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        cell: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        // custom messages
    }
});
```

**`.validate()` method DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/P46gL/**

---

**Quote OP:**

> *2)  When user click on a field error message should be cleared (per field)*

This is thanks to the `focusCleanup` option.  As you've already done, set it to `true` and when you click on the field with an error, the error clears.

```
$("#register_form").validate({
    focusCleanup: true,
    rules: {
       ....
```

**`focusCleanup` DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/P46gL/1/**

---

**Quote OP:**

> *3) On clicking reset button, every error should be cleared*

You would call the `resetForm()` method from within a `click` handler of the reset button.  This will immediately remove all error messages from the entire form and reset the validation plugin to its initial state.

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
    $("#register_form").validate().resetForm();  // clear out the validation errors
});
```

Make sure the reset button is `type="button"` or `type="reset"` or it will trigger validation.

```
<input type="reset" id="clearform" value="reset form" />
```

**Clear Errors DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/P46gL/3/**

---

**Clearing out the field data**

You can clear out the values of the fields by calling a JavaScript `.reset()` like this.

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
    var form = $("#register_form");
    form.validate().resetForm();      // clear out the validation errors
    form[0].reset();                  // clear out the form data
});
```

**Full Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/P46gL/4/**

Answer (score 4):

*`$("#register_form")[0].reset();`, form fields are getting clear, but error messages are not getting cleared.*

to do this you can put one more line below it:

```
function clearInputForm(){
   alert("");
   var validator1 = $( "#register_form" ).validate();
   validator1.resetForm();
   $("#register_form")[0].reset();
   $('.error').hide();
}
```

Although you should do this way:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   var validator = $("#register_form").validate({
       focusCleanup: true,
       rules: {
         // custom rules
       },
       messages: {
         // custom messages
       }
    });
    $('[type="reset"]').on('click', function(){
       validator.resetForm();
    });
});
```

---

You should put your `validator.resetForm();` in the click event of reset button.

Comment: with this, error message are not getting cleared at all

Comment: post some markup or better to create a jsfiddle for it.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works then try this approach (specially for clearing data purpose):

1-   Form html:

```
<input type='reset' class="button_grey resetForm" value='Reset'>
```

2-  Jquery validate

```
// you can add error fields
var validator = $("#clearform").validate({
      focusCleanup: true
});
```

3- Reset the form

```
$('[type="reset"]').on('click', function(){ 
      $("#clearform").closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); 
      $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked'); 
      validator.resetForm(); 
      return false;
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't do it this way. This manual hack will mess up the layout of the fields, and after that some errors may get displayed incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

All error messages will be cleared

```
$('.btn-reset').on('click', function () {
    $( "label.error" ).remove(); 
});
```