# Bootstrap Contact Form with jQuery Validation and AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I have a simple bootstrap contact form that I'm trying to implement with AJAX and jQuery validation. I feel like I'm pretty close but there are a few things that I can't get to work quite right. The forms validate according to input (ideally I'd like the phone number to be validated as digits; however, I'm new to contact form validation), but the contact form will still send even if the answers are not correct. In addition, the success box will always pop up after the form submits ... I'd like the form to not send if it is filled out incorrectly, and an error box to appear instead of the success. In addition, the email sends through the body of the message, but none of the variables get sent over. So the body of my message looks like:
Name:

Email: 

Phone: 

Message: 

With no variable appear after each.

I know this may be something simple but I'm very new to form validation and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Here's the HTML for the form:

```
<div class="form-group wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1s">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1.1s">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="form-group wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1.2s">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
      <textarea name="message" class="form-control " rows="4" cols="78" placeholder="Enter your message here."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="success"></div>
<div class="row wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="1.3s">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
    <div class="contact-btns">
      <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit" name="submit">
      <input type="reset" class="clear-buttom" value="Clear" name="clear">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
$status = array(
    'type' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Email sent!'
);

$val = $_POST['val'];
$toemail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];

$subject = 'Thelliotgroup Information Request';

$headers = "From: Thelliotgroup Website :: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = "<b>Name: </b>" . $name . "<br>";
$message .='<b>Email: </b>' . $email . "<br>";
$message .='<b>Phone: </b>' . $phone . "<br>";
$message .='<b>Message: </b>' . $msg;

$success = mail($toemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo json_encode($status);
die
```

Here's the AJAX and jQuery:

```
var form = $('.contact');
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function (data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    }, 'json');
    return false;
});


$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: {'val': $(".contact").serializeJSON()}
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    }
});

$(".contact").validate(
        {rules:
                    {name: "required",
                        email: {required: true, email: true},
                        phone: "required",
                        message: {required: true, maxlength: 300
                        }},
            errorClass: "error",
            highlight: function (label) {
                $(label).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
            },
            success: function (label) {
                label
                        //.text('Seems Perfect!').addClass('valid')
                        .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
            }
        });
```

I'd really appreciate any help you guys could give me to get this working properly.

**Edit**
Here's the new jQuery and AJAX code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var form = $(this); 
var post_url = form.attr('action'); 
$('.contact').validate({ 
    rules: {
        name: {
            rangelength: [2,40], 
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            rangelength: [2,40], 
            email: true,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            rangelength: [7,10],
            required: true
        },
        message: {
            minlength: 30,
            required: true
        },
        errorClass:"error",
        highlight: function(label) {
            $(label).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },

        success: function(label) {
            label
            .closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'email.php',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('.sent').fadeIn().fadeOut(5000);
            }
        });            
        return false; 
    }                  
});
```

});

Now I just need to figure out how to make it so that:

```
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
```

Which is located directly above the form, will fade in once the form is submitted.
I can't get it to work.

Thanks,
Brennan

Comment: Err, I cann't get how your jquery code is supposed to work, but at least you need to use event.preventDefault() to prevent the form submition. Check this manual, there is an example. http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @Vick, the jQuery Validate plugin automatically captures and blocks the default `submit` event; and its `submitHandler` is where you'd put the `ajax`.   Notice how the OP has an external `submit` handler with a separate Ajax `post` function.  No good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why you're doing a `.post()` (ajax) inside of a jQuery `submit` handler function while at the exact same time you have `.ajax()` inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` function. I don't get it.  Why are you using ajax twice?

I think it's best that you remove this entire function...

```
form.submit(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Because it is interfering with the plugin's `submitHandler` function.

Use the `submitHandler` to fire code upon the button `click` when the form is valid.  [This is where any ajax would belong](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler).

---

**EDIT**:

You've put `errorClass`, `highlight` and `success` ***inside*** the `rules` option...

```
rules: {
    name: {
        ....
    },
    email: {
        ....
    },
    phone: {
        ....
    },
    message: {
        ....
    },
    errorClass:"error",
    highlight: function(label) {
        ....        
    },
    success: function(label) {
        ....
    }
},
```

**This is wrong**.  `errorClass`, `highlight` and `success` are **siblings** of the `rules` and `submitHandler` options.

Also, when using `highlight`, it's best to use `unhighlight` along with it to undo whatever you did with `highlight`.

```
rules: {
    // only your rules here
},
errorClass:"error",
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-error');
},
submitHandler: function(form) { 
    $.ajax({
        // your options
    });            
    return false; 
}
```

---

For clearing out the form within the Ajax `success` option...

```
$('#myform').validate().resetForm(); // reset validation
form[0].reset();                     // clear out the form data
```

Comment: So what I was trying to do was on submit, display the success message above the form and then fade it out. Obviously it's not the right spot, but not quite sure how to do this, really new to AJAX and this is my first real attempt at it. Not quite sure how to pop up the error message either.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, you would review the jQuery `ajax` page to find the appropriate callback function for your fadeout.  I think you'd want `success` or `complete`.  As long as you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, the entire `ajax` function would be inside the Validate plugin's `submitHandler`.

Comment: alright so after looking around I've reworked the code and got it almost working. The validation and submitting works perfectly, I just can't figure out how to fadeIn the <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div> that I have located directly above the form. I edited my original post to show the new code.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, You cannot fade out `$(form)` because within the `submitHandler`, the  `form` argument represents the form validation object, not your `<form>` element.  Simply adjust the jQuery selector to target the form element instead.

Comment: Ahhh gotcha, alright so take a look at the Edit above, I modified my code and now when the form submits, a success box appears in place of the contact form, which is not what I want. Ideally I'd like the success message to appear above the contact form (why I have the "alert-success" div above the form) and fade out. What do I need to modify to do that?

Edit: Ahh I see that I'm fading out the form still, let me rework it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, you cannot attach `$(form)` to `fadeOut` because `form` does not represent the form element in this context.  You'll need to select the form element itself... like `$('#myform')` or whatever.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, put something like `id="successDiv"` on the `div`.  Then just select it... `$('#successDiv').fadeIn(......` or whatever.

Comment: Check my code above. Got it working correctly (hopefully that's the right syntax?). Now my only problem is the field icon background to the left of the form doesn't highlight green when the field gets filled in.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, just a tip... if you are trying to grab a single element, then using a `class` selector is not good practice, since the `class` selector _could_ represent more than one element.  For grabbing a single element, use `id` or any jQuery selector more specific than `class`.

Comment: That makes sense, just altered it to called the ID #sent instead of the class. Is there a way with AJAX to automatically clear all the fields once the email is sent? I'm sure there is a way I've just never done it.

Comment: @BrennanKarrer, see my edited answer regarding problems with your edited code.  Also, we typically do not continue to answer lots of new unrelated followup questions after the original question is answered.  Feel free to post a new question if needed.  Anyway, no you cannot clear the form with Ajax itself... that would be done within the Ajax `success` callback after your fade effects.  Let me find the thread...  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22021014/594235

Comment: Ahhhhh, sorry for all of the questions but I really appreciate all your help. Thanks so much!